# In javascript you are not limited to the properties in the official list, why and what is this feature called

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and there is something I don't understand. Take for example the .splice method which w3schools say has the following syntax: array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX). However in the parenthesis after .splice  where 'index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX' are, in Javascript you seem to not just be able to use the properties in the official syntax list, instead you seem to be able to add in any other code you want, for example as in this working line of code below:

```
notPlaying.splice(notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber), 1);
```

So in this case the indexOf method becomes a property? of the array.splice method and indexOf is used in the line of code, even though indexOf is not a property of .splice in the syntax list. So in Javascript, you are clearly not limited to the properties listed in the official syntax, you seem to be able to add in any other code you want? into the property list or line of code. But my question is what is this same feature of Javascript called, I am looking for a clear explanation and  good quality reference if possible that explains this feature of javascript, so I can understand it better and maybe see if it has any limitations. I hope people understand my question, it's quite hard to explain, but I can clarify further if necessary :)

Comment: `notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber)` *returns a number*, then that number is passed to `.splice`. It's as if you wrote `const index = notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber);` then afterwards wrote `notPlaying.splice(index, 1);`. You don't have to match the parameter names when calling functions.

Comment: I don't believe w3schools covers the basics of Javascript well enough. You might want to go through MDN's tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Comment: Read about how [`Method Definitions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) & [`Properties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/property/JavaScript) work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to the 3 people who posted above... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you think of them as parameters.

So in your example, "notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber)" is being *passed in as a value* for the ***index*** parameter. Does that make sense?

It's not that you're using a customer property, it's that you're using a piece of JavaScript to assign a value to a parameter within the splice() method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Benjamin James Kippax, that helps explain it a lot better yes, but "It's not that you're using a customer property, it's that you're using a piece of JavaScript to assign a value to a parameter within the splice() method." so is it ALWAYS the case in Javascript you can't have custom properties inside a property list, would it always be that you use a "you're using a piece of JavaScript to assign a value to a parameter within the splice() method" , the books don't seem to explain this well!

Comment: @Emma45; Yes that's correct. So in actual fact, you could replace "notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber)" with the number 6, for instance. It's just a way to get a value into the method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
notPlaying.splice(notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber), 1);
```

There are two function calls here: `notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber)` and `notPlaying.splice(..., 1)`.

[`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is called first. It returns the first position where its argument (the value of `audioNumber`) is present in the array (if it is present) or `-1` if it is not present in the array.

The value returned by `notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber)` is a number. It is then used as the first argument to [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

#### How to read a documentation

The documentation describes [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) as:

```
array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
```

In this definition, `start`, `deleteCount`, `item1`, `item2`, etc. are *symbolic names* for the arguments expected by the function. They **are not** properties of `Array.splice` or of `notPlaying`. As you can notice, the W3Schools tutorial you are following now uses different names for them. These names are useful to you to understand the purpose of the values to pass as arguments when you call the function. Internally it's possible that the function's implementation uses different names.

The pieces enclosed in square braces (`[` and `]`) in the definition denotes optional arguments. `Array.splice()` can be invoked as:

```
notPlaying.splice(2);
notPlaying.splice(3, 2);
notPlaying.splice(3, 2, 'abc');
notPlaying.splice(2, 1, 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk');
```

and in many other ways.
The `[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]` part basically denotes a list of values of any length (including an empty list).

Comment: Quality answer too, Have you thought of extending the answer?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation axiac

Comment: @Alex extending to what?

Comment: Well, you seem to dive in quite well into the subject, might as well add more references on how methods and params work.